# UICollectionView - multiple, different cells

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Using a `UICollectionView`, I'm trying to add another `UICollectionViewCell`. This first code shows the first Cell and it runs fine. The problem occurs when I'm trying to add another `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell"; // Default Cells

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *illustrationImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
illustrationImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[stackImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

UILabel *stackLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:12];
[stackLabel setText:[stackTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

And here I want to add a whole new Cell, with different content, to my `UICollectionView`. Whenever I run this code, the whole thing refuses to launch:

```
static NSString *newIdentifier = @"AddNewCell"; 

UICollectionViewCell *newCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:newIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *addNewImage = (UIImageView *)[newCell viewWithTag:120];
addNewImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[addNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; // This line makes the app crash

return cell;
return newCell;
```

**Error Message**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

I suspect this has something to do with the `indexPath.row`.
If I replace the `indexPath.row` section in the following code with "0", then it doesn't crash, but it won't be visible in the `UICollectionView`:

```
[addNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
```

Answer (score 3):

First, I assume you're running the code snippets you provided in the 
**collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:** method, not somewhere else in your code.

Also, you cannot create (nor return !!) two cells at once inside the said method. You should decide what cell you dequeue, instantiate and return based on the index path received as a param.

Now, about the "*index beyond bounds*" error you're receiving : you're trying to access an element of the array called `addNew` which is not actually present in the array at the moment you want to access it. In your case you try to access the second element of the array (index `1`)  and the array has only one element (at index `0`).

You may want to verify that the `addNew` array is properly initialized *before* you are accessing it.